# How to include a dependency to parent test classes for a submodule in a Gradle multiple project build?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a multiple project Gradle build in which a submodule need to reference some helper classes defined in the parent module test configuration.

In the submodule I've added the following definition:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(path: ':')
    testCompile project(path: ':', configuration: 'testCompile')
}
```

However the submodule test compilation faila because it is unable to resolve classes defined in the parent testCompile configuration.

How to reference the parent test configuration in a submodule in a Gradle build ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
compile project(project.parent.path)
testCompile project(project.parent.path, configuration: 'testCompile')
```

If you need configuration, you can find it like this:

```
project.parent.configurations.testCompile
```

**UPDATE**

Solution:

```
testCompile files(project.parent.sourceSets.test.output)
```

Comment: Nope, the line `testCompile project(project.parent.path, configuration: 'testCompile')` makes the build to fail with this message: `Could not find method project() for arguments [{configuration=testCompile}, :] on project ':nxf-drmaa'`

Comment: Did you try it with project.parent.configurations.testCompile instead of String? Am not sure that you can use String. I think actually you can use this: testCompile project.parent.configurations.testCompile

Comment: Well, using `testCompile project.parent.configurations.testCompile` I got a StackOverflowError ... that's quite ironic ;)

Comment: How does your settings.gradle looks like? Is it really a child project?

Comment: You can also try this: `testCompile files(project.parent.sourceSets.test.output)`